# Timezone handling in AWS with C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timezone

**Timezone usage**
A stored object in the database has an UTC timestamp. The user requests this element and should receive the element with a timestamp in a configured timezone.

**How to keeping the timezone up to date**
On-premise, we stored the timezone data (offset, DST, etc.) for the next 5 years in our database and updated these values manually, if these 5 years were over or there were some timezone changes. (legacy code...)

Because we are now migrating to AWS, we also wanted to automate the timezone update handling.

We looked into TimeZoneInfo so we don't have to worry about timezone changes and let the OS handle that. But that won't work for AWS Lambda because it only "knows" UTC.

Is there any AWS Service or extension, which provides a localized timestamp from an UTC timestamp and a timezone?
Or a completely different approach to handle timezones changes?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you mean by the first paragraph? (I can think of a number of possible meanings, depending on how sophisticated your understanding of time zone data is.) I *suspect* that my [Noda Time project](https://nodatime.org) can help anyway, but it would be good to get more clarity on the requirements. (In particular, a concrete example of when TimeZoneInfo would give the wrong answer would be useful.)

Comment: Wow, that's a big change to the question - going from 'but that won't work for AWS Lambda as TimeZoneInfo gets the timezones from the OS.' to 'But that won't work for AWS Lambda because it only "knows" UTC.'

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, also you will always be a legend

Comment: FYI, the [base container image for dotnet on AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-image.html) includes time zone data already.  `yum list installed | grep tzdata` on the latest image with no modifications shows version 2022e, which is the latest available for Amazon Linux 2022.  I presume they'll have a 2022f update soon.  Anyway - `tzdata` provides compatible data for `TimeZoneInfo` on .NET - so "Lambda only knows about UTC" is incorrect.  It may be different for other deployment models though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really surprised that AWS Lambda doesn't actually have full complement of time zone information, but assuming that's actually the case, you could certainly use my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) project. That comes with the most recent [time zone data from IANA](https://iana.org/tz) baked into it, and you can [load an updated file](https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/tzdb) (usually obtained from nodatime.org via polling for changes) if you need to stay *really* up to date.

I'd personally recommend trying to adopt Noda Time throughout the codebase as a clearer date/time API, but if you absolutely wanted to stick to `DateTime` etc everywhere else, you could have a method such as:

```cs
public static DateTime ConvertUtcToZone(DateTime utc, string zoneId)
{
    var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[zoneId];
    var instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utc);
    var zoned = instant.InZone(zone);
    return zoned.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
}
```

Comment: Even if I don't know if I explained the question correctly, this solution is surely an improvement to what we have now.
With this solution, we only have to redeploy a file instead of updating the database AND there is no problem with the OS timezones